# How to send an html email with variables

Tags: variables, html-email, python-3.7

I want to send an email with bold variables

```
body = "Time: " + str(time) + "\nStatus: " + status + "\nTemp.: " + str('{:,g}'.format(currentTemp)) + " °C Feels like: " + str(
    '{:,g}'.format(feelsTemp)) + " °C\nWind speed: " + str(windSpeed) + " m/s Clouds: " + str(
    clouds) + "%\nVisibility: " + str(visibility) + " km/h Hu: " + str(humidity) + "%"
msg = MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('WeatherNotification', 'utf-8')
```

What I want:

**Status:** Clear sky

**Temp.:** 13.5 °C

e.t.c

What I get:

Status: Clear sky

Temp.: 13.5 °C

Answer (score 0):

try this one`"\nStatus: " "<b>" + status +"<b>"`

```
"\nTemp.:" "<b>"+ str('{:,g}'.format(currentTemp)) +"<b>"
```

Comment: Didn't work, I need to make the html file with bold text and plain variables, but I don't know how to paste variables into html file

Comment: This should work, but also with `MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8')` change "plain" to "html". I think.